# Making a given Java class more generic and flexible

Tags: java, class, wildcard, subtype

I am given a class `Shop` that maintains a collection of items of type `T`. It provides buy and sell functions for single or multiple items and uses a `List<T>` as a container for buying and selling:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Shop<T> {
    List<T> stock;

    public Shop() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
    public T buy() { 
        return stock.remove(0);
    }
    void sell(T item) {
        stock.add(item);
    }

    void buy(int n, List<T> items) {
        for (T e : stock.subList(0, n)) {
            items.add(e);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) stock.remove(0);
    }

    void sell(List<T> items) {
        for (T e : items) {
            stock.add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to modify this class so that I can buy/sell items with any `Collection` type...not just `List`. I figured I would start by commenting out most everything and trying to convert things one by one, beginning with the `stock` :

```
 public class Shop<T> {
   // List<T> stock;
      Collection<T> stock;

   // public Shop() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
      public Shop() { stock = new Collection<T>(); }            
      ...
      ... 
  }
```

The first declaration works, but trying to instantiate the interface in the constructor, as expected, does not work. But as far as I can tell, `stock` needs to be a `Collection` so that I can use any `Collection` subtype in the other functions that deal with it. And I'm pretty sure I cannot use a wildcard as a type parameter in this case. So what exactly can I do to construct the `stock` here...or how should I declare the `stock` differently in the first place?

Comment: You can start by making `Collection<T>` to become `Collection<? extends T>` and every other place where you're using parameterized types

Comment: But how can I construct the `stock`? I cannot instantiate a `Collection` interface.

Comment: You don't instantiate a `Collection`, during runtime, your actual container class can be any of the interfaces that extend `Collection`. The flexibility I've prescribed here governs only what the containers will contain, which is an child of `T`

Comment: Also, would I be right in thinking that `toArray()` would be useful here in replacing the list-specific, index-related operations?

Comment: correct. You could easily make use of a `Set` the same way you'd use a `List` by doing that. Good thinking

Comment: Good to know. Now, though, I can't use `add` in the same way. According to the compiler: `Shop.java:12: add(capture#441 of ? extends T) in java.util.Collection<capture#441 of ? extends T> cannot be applied to (T)
    stock.add(item);
         ^`
I tried to address this by casting `stock` to a `LinkedList`, but that gave warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual collection implementation you use inside your class is completely immaterial to the clients/users of the class as long as your interface definition accepts `Collection`, i.e.

```
void buy(int n, List<T> items)
void sell(List<T> items)
```

should be

```
void buy(int n, Collection<T> items)
void sell(Collection<T> items)
```

This will not restrict anyone to use only `List` types. Then, your internal member `stock` can be and should be instantiated with any concrete subtype of `Collection`.

Comment: So the stock can be instantiated as (for example) a `List`, but really considered to be a `Collection`?

Comment: Yes, because List is a Collection.